# Is it better/faster to resize an image with CSS, or with the <img> tag?

Tags: html, css, performance

I was wondering what is the better/faster way to resize an image.

Normally I would resize an image with CSS, but a college told me that by using the `width` attribute, e.g.

```
<img width="size" [..]>
```

the browser would render the page faster.

Anyone know if this is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`width` and `height` are semantic in the case of `img`es and `object`s. They provide metadata for images so it is completely fine IMO to rely on those attributes in order to tell the user agent that it should presize the element to X dimensions prior to the image fully rendering.

Comment: One advantage to this (at least in the past - I imagine it's still valid) is less fluctuation in the visible page structure while things are loading.

Answer (score 5):

It would be even faster if you resized the actual image, and not the dimensions you want the browser to render it to.

Comment: The point of specifying width and height is that the browser can allocate space on the page *before* the image is loaded, therefore eliminating the need to rearrange elements when the images are loaded.

Comment: @Tomas - Agreed. However, declaring the size of the image to the browser is not the same as asking the browser to resize it for you. As I see it, specifying the size in the image tag or in CSS makes no difference performance-wise.

Answer (score 4):

You should set width and height properties of each img tag. It speeds up rendering page because browser doesn't wait for css files and images loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If we stick with presentation vs. structure, I'd put your image sizes in CSS. Speed really doesn't matter these days, the browser has to wait for the images to be loaded anyway, so the speed it takes to compose and render the page isn't really measureable, well unless your CSS fails to load...

Answer (score 0):

Bit difficult to give definitive answers for very general questions like this, but I think it’s generally better *not* to resize images in HTML or CSS — make the image file the right dimensions.

Ignoring that, I don’t think there’s likely to be any perceptible difference between the two.