# What image loads faster? HTML

Tags: html, css, image

Hello I wanted to ask you if it matters when I have a huge image in my directory and I want to load it on a website like this:

```
<img src="file.png" width="90px">
```

or will it take a longer time than if it would be already rezized?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb No it's a question about speed not about how to rezize the images

Comment: If you read the question you would see its about performance and site loading.  There is also another similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098751/is-it-better-faster-to-resize-an-image-with-css-or-with-the-img-tag

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4098778/1033615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:  It's much faster to load a resized image.

The browser will still download the full sized image, and then scale as needed based on the size you've given.  Bandwidth will not be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, PNG files are loaded slower than JPG files

Comment: it's not the question I was asking for but: So if I can choose between a png file a a jpg file I should choose a jpg?

Comment: Yes, Png files have larger size

Comment: Oh ok thanks ;) I going to take that in mind

Comment: more info: png or jpg size depends on image. If it some real picture with lots of colors, jpg will be smaller, but if it is like some chart for example or image do not have lots of different colors, png will be much more smaller and even perfect quality, not like jpg, that will loose some quality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, loading bigger image takes more time.