# Does image resizing using the IMG tag properties affect performance (For thumbnails)?

Tags: html

If I have an image sized 2000x2000px, and it's compressed so doesn't weigh much in KB, will resizing it using the HTML IMG tag affect performance:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width="320" height="320">
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width="640" height="640">
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width="1024" height="1024">
```

as opposed to having actual 3 thumbnail files sized 320x320px, 640x640px, 1024x1024px?

Should I create separate thumbnails for every image uploaded or just stick to having one and resize in HTML? Because I need to upload many images

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098751/is-it-better-faster-to-resize-an-image-with-css-or-with-the-img-tag

Comment: Nice, I guess I should delete this post before it's marked duplicate then :)
But also - does it make sense to create 3 thumbnails for each uploaded image? (Say I have tens of thousands of images uploaded - each will have its own "thumbnails" folder?)

Comment: well it depends, say you would really have tens of thousands then i would recommend to go with the img tag to resize them, if it's just a few, upload each seperately with the right size

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it better/faster to resize an image with CSS, or with the <img> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098751/is-it-better-faster-to-resize-an-image-with-css-or-with-the-img-tag)

Comment: Nope because this is CSS vs IMG tag, not actual size vs IMG tag

Answer (score 1):

Decompressing a large image will use more CPU. Storing the pixel data in memory for a larger image will use more memory. It will affect performance.

Whether or not this is a **significant** impact on performance will depend on your particular use case, the devices rendering the website, and how often you do it. The usual provisos about premature optimisation and the importance of focusing on bottlenecks over hypotheticals apply.

Comment: I just checked and if I create small thumbnails and lower their quality using imagick or GD, I get very small size for each thumbnail, maybe 70KB. But does it make sense to have 3 thumbnails created for each uploaded photo if I now upload tens of thousands of photos? I'm just curious as to what they do in services like Google Drive or iCloud Photos